# Is Sarah experiencing any psychological disorders?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-two

From the first time I played Season 2, I was wondering what Carlos [cmiiw] means when he told me that I should avoid his daughter. I was wondering if this was because she has some psychological disorders. Which psychology disorders does Sarah have, if any?

Comment: I finished episode 2, and I don't know yet.

Comment: It  sounds like what you really want to know is why Carlos said to avoid his daughter, and that you're   just assuming it's because she has psychological disorder.

Comment: @Wipqozn Well Carlos also said that Sarah isn't like a normal girl...

Answer (score 2):

While Sarah seems to have some mental fragility, she also showed to be much stronger than Carlos expected her to be. This becomes more apparent in the later episodes. She still freezes out of fear sometimes, but is capable of handling shocking moments without completely collapsing.

I think she's just highly emotional, which is exacerbated more due to her father shielding her from real life.

Answer (score 0):

I think she didn't really have a disorder until she figured out what was actually happening with the world. Like how Carlos said it would "break her reality" if she knew what was going on. I think she ended up with Schizophrenia disorder. Its distorts the way a person thinks or acts. Also, it causes paranoia, and hallucinations.
She had paranoia. Also, she was not thinking clearly sometimes. I don't know if this is the mental disorder she has, but I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 0):

She most likely has an anxiety disorder.

**Source:** http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Sarah_(Video_Game)